# The priority of operator * in AT&T assembly language

Tags: assembly, operator-precedence

Here I have a question. What is the priority of the operator * in assembly language?

For example:

```
*0x804983c(,%eax,4)
```

Does it mean `( %eax * 4 ) + *0x804983c` or `*( %eax * 4 + 0x804983c )`?

Thanks!

Comment: I prefer *( %eax * 4 + 0x804983c ), but is there any specification to refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is not an operator. There is no operator in assembly as such (operators are a concept only present in higher level languages).

In AT&T syntax, * is what denotes a [register or memory branch target](http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax).

You're not showing the complete instruction, but assuming it was a jmp, this will jump to what is stored at `0 + %eax * 4 + 0x804983c` (following the standard memory reference of `offset(base,index,scale)`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're right, the preceding code comes from a jump instruction.